# acts_as_api undefined local variable with ActiveModel::Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

i have this ActiveModel in my rails 4 app.

```
class MyModeltest
    include ActiveModel::Model
    acts_as_api
    attr_accessor :title, :content

    api_accessible :public do |template|
        template.add :title
        template.add :content
    end
end
```

i call this model form my controller and this return an error:

> undefined local variable or method `acts_as_api' for ...

So, is possible to call acts_as_api under an ActiveModel?
if yes, could you show me how do this?

thanks in advance

To be more clear, my problem is not with static variable acts_as_api, is with the gem "acts_as_api" that is not recognized by the ActiveModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of acts_as_api.

If you want to use it with a non-`ActiveRecord` class, you have to extend your class with `extend ActsAsApi::Base`.

In your case this would be

```
class MyModeltest
  include ActiveModel::Model
  extend ActsAsApi::Base
  acts_as_api
  attr_accessor :title, :content

  api_accessible :public do |template|
    template.add :title
    template.add :content
  end
end
```

You can find an example in the wiki:

https://github.com/fabrik42/acts_as_api/wiki/Declaring-api-templates-for-any-class%21-%28no-orms%29

If you need further assistance, just let me know. :)

Comment: Hi @chris_b, thank's for your reply, this work like a charm.
i have posted another question about acts_as_api, this is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356290/format-xml-with-properties-with-acts-as-api), could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use constants inside a model then you will have to make it in uppercase and also initialize it. Define it as

```
class MyModeltest
    include ActiveModel::Model
    ACTS_AS_API = false
    attr_accessor :title, :content

    api_accessible :public do |template|
        template.add :title
        template.add :content
    end
end
```

And to call it outside the class use, MyModeltest::ACTS_AS_API

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
i suppose that is not clear what happen, my fault. The problem is that the "gem acts_as_api" is not recognized in the ActiveModel.
this is the link of the project to be more clear:
[act_as_api](http://fabrik42.github.io/acts_as_api/)